# Простое ли предложение "Скатился на 700 метров и решил, что это удовлетворительно" и почему?

Tags: пунктуация, сложное-предложение

Я вот считаю, что простое, потому что у него 2 сказуемых (скатился и решил) относится к одному подлежащему, которое опущено. Получается грамматическая основа одна.

Правильная ли логика? Если нет, то как нужно конкретно в этом случаи или аналогичных, размышлять?
Правильно ли расставлены запятые (предложение в заголовке)?
Почему нужна запятая перед "что"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Скатился на 700 метров и решил, что это удовлетворительно**

Это **сложноподчиненное предложение** с придаточным изъяснительным, запятая ставится перед **союзом ЧТО**.

Главное предложение **неполное** (подлежащее пропущено и определяется по контексту). Предложение **осложнено однородными сказуемыми** (***скатился и решил***), запятая перед одиночным союзом И не ставится.

Придаточное предложение относится ко второму сказуемому (***решил***).